# The specified task executable location is invalid while running GitLab CI Job

Tags: .net-core, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to set up CICD for my .NET Core application with GitLab CI.

Let's start with my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image : microsoft/dotnet:latest
before_script:
  - 'cd Backend'
  - 'dotnet restore'
build:
 stage: build
 script:
  - 'dotnet build -c Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Properties/PublishProfiles/WebioProfile.pubxml'
 only:
   - cicd_test
```

And `WebioProfile` I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://xxx.hostingasp.pl/</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>03120c29-ae98-4c30-9b8c-7ec70f6642fd</ProjectGuid>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>ssl3.xxxx.hostingasp.pl</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>xxxx.hostingasp.pl</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>user</UserName>
    <Password>password</Password>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

After `git push origin cicd_test`

I got this error GitLab Job console

> Restore completed in 58.11 ms for
>   /builds/username/project/Backend/Backend.csproj.
>   Backend ->
>   /builds/username/project/Backend/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/Backend.dll
>   Backend ->
>   /builds/username/project/Backend/obj/Release/netcoreapp2.1/PubTmp/Out/
>   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.203/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/build/netstandard1.0/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(171,5):
>   error MSB6004: The specified task executable location
>   "%ProgramW6432%/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" is invalid.
>   [/builds/username/project/Backend/Backend.csproj]
>
> Build FAILED.

From what I see, `%ProgramW6432%` is some kind of variable that isnt set? But where I can change it?

Worth to notice, deploying using same commands as in `.gitlab-ci.yml` works fine if I run it localy from VS CLI

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: Seems like a bug that is ought to be fixed: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/25887

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a workaround

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error when trying to publish to Azure app service from a Mac.

This issue helped me solve the problem: https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/241

Instead of using the 'dotnet publish' command it can be done using msbuild:

`msbuild project-name.csproj -c Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=publishprofile.pubxml`